# Concatenar valor SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
DECLARE @CDOC VARCHAR(254)

SET @CDOC = 'AGF2019-15'

SELECT t.*
FROM TDOCUMENTAL t
WHERE t.CDOC = CONCAT (
        SUBSTRING(@CDOC, 1, 3)
        ,SUBSTRING(@CDOC, 9, 1)
        )
```

Estoy tratando de extraer los valores `AGF` y cualquier número que este después del guion `-`.

La idea es obtener algo así `AGF15`.

El problema que tengo es que cuando el valor después del `-` es por ejemplo `135` mi consulta no funciona.

¿Alguien me puede orientar como puedo mejorar el query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el patrón es siempre el mismo para los códigos de documento, esto debería funcionar:

```
DECLARE @CDOC VARCHAR(254)

SET @CDOC = 'AGF2019-15585'

SELECT CONCAT (
        substring(@CDOC, 1, 3)
        ,substring(@CDOC, charindex('-', @CDOC) + 1, len(@CDOC))
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta puede ser una opción para eliminar el valor central. La función STUFF indica que a partir de la posición 4 cambié la cantidad de caracteres de la posición del guión menos 3 por una cadena vacía.

```
DECLARE @CDOC VARCHAR(254)

SET @CDOC = 'AGF2019-15'

SELECT t.*
FROM TDOCUMENTAL t
WHERE t.CDOC =STUFF( @CDOC, 4, CHARINDEX('-', @CDOC) - 3, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

A menos que el valor de `@CDOC` se corresponda con alguna columna de una tabla, te sugiero que resuelvas esto por fuera del filtro `WHERE`, una forma es reconstruyendo la variable así:

```
DECLARE @CDOC VARCHAR(254)

SET @CDOC = 'AGF2019-135'

SET @CDOC = SUBSTRING(@CDOC,1, 3) + RIGHT(@CDOC, LEN(@CDOC) - CHARINDEX('-', @CDOC) )
SELECT @CDOC

AGF135
```

Con `SUBSTRING` recortamos los primeros tres caracteres y con `RIGHT(@CDOC, LEN(@CDOC) - CHARINDEX('-', @CDOC)` tomamos los caracteres luego del `-`